# Powershell Remove subfolders where name not in sql output

Tags: powershell

Trying to delete sub folders where the name is not part of a SQL output. Tried the below but -exclude doesnt seem to exclude any thing. Am I missing something obvious?

```
$SQL = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT id FROM files" -Database dbname -ServerInstance .\SQLEXPRESS
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\files -Exclude $SQL | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: the `-Exclude` parameter [and `-Include`] only seem to work on _file names_. this makes no sense, but that is how it seems to work. to do what you want, you will need to add a `Where-Object` pipeline step that filters out the excluded dirs.

Comment: Thanks that explains it

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Query = "SELECT id FROM files"

$SqlParams = @{
    Query          = $Query
    Database       = 'dbname'
    ServerInstance = '.\SQLEXPRESS'
}

$ValuesFromSqlTable = Invoke-Sqlcmd @SqlParams

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\files | Where-Object {$PSITEM.Name -notin $ValuesFromSqlTable} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

This is about how I would do something like this.
As Lee mentioned, you want to use Where-Object to filter your search.

Comment: The invoke sql like should be:  $ValuesFromSqlTable = Invoke-Sqlcmd @SqlParams| select-object -expand id. Reason is that Powershell where works with arrays